# Evaluating double integrals by inspection

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

I'm trying to use as much information about the domain to be able to solve the integral without actually integrating. The problem is:

> Evaluate $\oint\limits_C {(x\sin ({y^2}) - {y^2})dx + ({x^2}y\cos ({y^2}) +3x)dy} $ where $C$ is the counterclockwise boundary of the trapezoid with vertices $(0,-2),(1,-1),(1,1),(0,2)$.

**My attempt**

It's clear that we can use Green's theorem to rewrite the integral, i.e.

$$\oint\limits_C {(x\sin ({y^2}) - {y^2})dx + ({x^2}y\cos ({y^2})+3x)dy}  = \iint\limits_T {(3 - 2y)dA}$$

The interesting thing about $T$ is that it is a trapezoid, the area which is quite easy to find without integration. I got it to be $3$. Now, based on what I've seen in the textbook, it is written as following
$$(3-2y)\times (\text{area of trapezoid})$$

If we would not have the integrand, the integral would be $3$. How should we interpret $(3-2y)$. What $y$ value is needed? The key says it is $9$. Based on this, $y=0$, but why?

Comment: Did you type your question correctly? I don't see how you got the $3$ in your integrand $3-2y$.

Comment: @KittyL, I found a type in the question. I forgot the $3x$. Based on this correction, does my conclusion (i.e. application of Green's theorem) make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integrand should be $3+2y$. Your idea is correct. The term $3$ multiplies the area gives you the $9$.

Now imagine integrating $y$ over the symmetric trapezoid region. $f(x,y)=y$ is a plane that is positive over the region above $x$-axis, and negative over the region below $x$-axis, and it is symmetric. Can you see what it should be then?

Comment: Thank you! I think I get it. Since the domain is symmetric, the positive and negative sides cancel out, which leads to zero (for $2y$ term). Thus, the area is $9$. +1